# First Unique Character in a String

Tags: python

Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return its index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.

```
first_unique('leetcode')  # 0
first_unique('loveleetcode')  # 2
```

I came up with the following solution.  How can I make it more efficient for very long input strings?

```
def first_unique(self, s):
    if s == '':
        return -1

    for item in s:
        if s.count(item) == 1:
            return s.index(item)
            break

    return -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version isn't bad for few cases with "nice" strings... but using count is quite expensive for long "bad" strings, I'd suggest you cache items, for instance:

```
def f1(s):
    if s == '':
        return -1
    for item in s:
        if s.count(item) == 1:
            return s.index(item)
            break
    return -1


def f2(s):
    cache = set()

    if s == '':
        return -1
    for item in s:
        if item not in cache:
            if s.count(item) == 1:
                return s.index(item)
            else:
                cache.add(item)

    return -1

import timeit
import random
import string

random.seed(1)

K, N = 500, 100000
data = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits)
               for _ in range(K))

print(
    timeit.timeit('f1(data)', setup='from __main__ import f1, data', number=N))
print(
    timeit.timeit('f2(data)', setup='from __main__ import f2, data', number=N))
```

The results on my laptop are:

```
32.05926330029437
4.267771588590406
```

The version using cache gives you 8x speed up factor vs yours wich is using count function all the time. So, my general advice would be... cache as much as possible whether it's possible

EDIT:

I've added Patrick Haugh version to the benchmark and it gave `10.92784585620725`

EDIT2:

I've added Mehmet Furkan Demirel version to the benchmark and it gave `10.325440507549331`

EDIT3:

I've added wim version to the benchmark and it gave `12.47985351744839`

CONCLUSION:

I'd use the version i've proposed initially using a simple cache without relying on Python counter modules, it's not necessary (in terms of performance)

Answer (score 6):

My solution uses `Counter` form the `collections` module.

```
from collections import Counter
def first_unique(s):
    c = Counter(s)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if c[s[i]] == 1:
            return i
    return -1
```

Comment: You can roll your own Counter pretty easily.

Comment: d = {}
for char in s:
    if char in d:
        d[char] += 1
    else:
        d[char] = 1

Comment: even simpler without an if: `for char in s: d[char] = d.get(char, 0) + 1`

Answer (score 4):

Suave version:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

def first_unique(s):
    counter = OrderedCounter(s)
    try:
        return counter.values().index(1)
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

---

Weird version:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

def first_unique(s):
    nah = {0}-{0}  # funny pair of eyes 
    yeah = OrderedDict()
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if c not in nah:
            try:
                del yeah[c]
            except KeyError:
                yeah[c] = i
            else:
                nah.add(c)
    return next(yeah.itervalues(), -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a for loop to iterate the `String` from the beginning and at each index, I would check if the rest of the `String` has the character at the current index by using Substring.

Try this:

```
def firstUniqChar(word):
for i in range(0,len(word)):  ## iterate through the string
    if not word[i] in word[i+1:len(word)]: ## check if the rest contains that char
        index=i
        break
return index
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The idea in this solution is to use a pair of defaultdicts. The first one contains an integer count of each character and the second contains the index location of the latest character read.

After reading all of the characters, a list comprehension is used to find all of those that only occurred once (`result`).  The minimum index locations of these characters (found in our other defaultdict `order`) will give us the first index location of non-repeating characters.

```
from collections import defaultdict
# To Create random string:
from string import ascii_lowercase
from random import choice, randint, seed

# Create a random sentence of 1000 words (1-8 characters each).
seed(0)
gibberish = ' '.join(''.join(choice(ascii_lowercase) 
                             for _ in range(randint(1, 8))) 
                     for _ in range(1000))
print(len(gibberish))
# Output: 5614

# Solution.
def first_unique(s):
    dd = defaultdict(int)
    order = defaultdict(int)
    for n, c in enumerate(s):
        dd[c] += 1
        order[c] = n
    result = [order[c] for c in dd if dd[c] == 1]
    return min(result) if result else -1
```

## Timings

```
%timeit first_unique(gibberish)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.13 ms per loop

@wim solution:
%timeit first_unique(gibberish)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.06 ms per loop

@PatrickHaugh solution (which is much easier to understand than mine):
%timeit first_unique(gibberish)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.2 ms per loop

@BPL solution:
%timeit f1(gibberish)
10 loops, best of 3: 39.2 ms per loop
%timeit f2(gibberish)
1000 loops, best of 3: 890 µs per loop
```

Using a much shorter sentence of twenty words (133 characters):

```
%timeit first_unique(gibberish)
10000 loops, best of 3: 62.8 µs per loop

@wim solution:
%timeit first_unique(gibberish)
10000 loops, best of 3: 169 µs per loop

@PatrickHaugh solution:
%timeit first_unique(gibberish)
10000 loops, best of 3: 101 µs per loop

@BPL solution:
%timeit f1(gibberish)
10000 loops, best of 3: 55.1 µs per loop
%timeit f2(gibberish)
10000 loops, best of 3: 31 µs per loop
```

## Test cases.

```
s1 = 'leetcode'
s2 = 'loveleetcode'

>>> first_unique(s1)
0

>>> first_unique(s2)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class Main{

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Input String : GirishRathi");
                System.out.println("Output String : " +firstUniqChar("GirishRathi"));
            }

            public static int firstUniqChar(String s) {

                Map<Character , Integer> map = new HashMap<Character , Integer>();

                for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
                    char current = s.charAt(i);
                    if(map.containsKey(current)) {
                        map.put(current, -1);
                    }else {
                        map.put(current , i);
                    }
                }

                int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                for(char c : map.keySet()) {
                    if(map.get(c) > -1 && map.get(c) < min) {
                        min = map.get(c);
                    }
                }

                return min == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : min;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

A first unique character in a string has below property.

1. The starting index and end index of the character should be the same.
2. Its starting index should be less than other unique character's starting index.

```
public int firstUniqChar(String s) {
        int result = s.length();
        for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++){
            int i = s.indexOf(c);
            if(i != -1 && i == s.lastIndexOf(c)){
                result = Math.min(result, i);
            }
        }
        return result == s.length() ? -1 : result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this approach?

```
def first_unique_letter(text):
    for c in range(0, len(text)):
        if text[c] not in text[0:c] and text[c] not in text[c + 1:len(text)]:
            return text[c]
    return "_"
```

it breaks the for cycle after finding the first unique letter, so it's better than wait for the entire cycle to finish. It returns a '_' when no character is unique

Comment: I appreciate explained answer. But please avoid asking (even rhetoric) questions in answers.

Answer (score 0):

The below code iterates the string and checks if the character is present anywhere else in the string. Once found, it will skip the current character and move to the next.

```
def getUniqueCharacter(s):     
    for i in range(len(s)):
        flag=0
        for j in range(len(s)):
            if i==j:
                continue
            if s[i]==s[j]:
                flag=1
                break
    if flag==0:
        return i
return -1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: And please make sure your code is _correct_. This code has an obvious `IndentationError`.

Comment: Note that this question is nearly five and a half years old and already has eight answers. _Specifically_, how does your answer improve upon what's already here?

Answer (score 0):

Newer python versions (>= 3.7) preserve insertion order in `dict`s and `Counter`s.

```py
def firstUniqChar(self, s: str) -> int:
    for key in (ctr := Counter(s)):
        if ctr[key] < 2:
            return s.index(key)
    return -1
```